# Covid-19 World Case Report Beta 0.1

Tags: python, sorting, database, pandas, matplotlib

I am a self-learned programmer and this is my first program. I would really appreciate any critique on my approach.

The program should automatically download the who data file to the folder these files are in.

#### file: who_report.py

```
# https://covid19.who.int/
# https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-data.csv
# https://www.kaggle.com/tanuprabhu/population-by-country-2020


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import os

# local imports
from who_report_helper import get_who_statistics, get_range_date


"""
This script will download the latest Covid statistics directly from WHO and write it to a local csv.
Then parse 9 countries statistics to compare.
Then it will generate a mat plot chart saving to a png after.
"""


def create_report(cdf, ytd, end):
    # from pprint import pprint  # Uncomment for list of country codes to compare other country stats
    # countries = dict(zip(cdf.Country.unique(), cdf.Country_code.unique()))
    # pprint(countries)
    US = cdf[(cdf['Country_code'] == "US") & (cdf['Date_reported'] <= end) & (cdf['Date_reported'] >= ytd)]  # US
    MX = cdf[(cdf['Country_code'] == "MX") & (cdf['Date_reported'] <= end) & (cdf['Date_reported'] >= ytd)]  # Mexico
    BR = cdf[(cdf['Country_code'] == "BR") & (cdf['Date_reported'] <= end) & (cdf['Date_reported'] >= ytd)]  # Brazil
    GB = cdf[(cdf['Country_code'] == "GB") & (cdf['Date_reported'] <= end) & (cdf['Date_reported'] >= ytd)]  # UK
    DE = cdf[(cdf['Country_code'] == "DE") & (cdf['Date_reported'] <= end) & (cdf['Date_reported'] >= ytd)]  # Germany
    IT = cdf[(cdf['Country_code'] == "IT") & (cdf['Date_reported'] <= end) & (cdf['Date_reported'] >= ytd)]  # Italy
    FR = cdf[(cdf['Country_code'] == "FR") & (cdf['Date_reported'] <= end) & (cdf['Date_reported'] >= ytd)]  # France
    ES = cdf[(cdf['Country_code'] == "ES") & (cdf['Date_reported'] <= end) & (cdf['Date_reported'] >= ytd)]  # Spain
    IN = cdf[(cdf['Country_code'] == "IN") & (cdf['Date_reported'] <= end) & (cdf['Date_reported'] >= ytd)]  # India
    RU = cdf[(cdf['Country_code'] == "RU") & (cdf['Date_reported'] <= end) & (cdf['Date_reported'] >= ytd)]  # Russia

    # Setting up the figure and its grids to plot
    grid_size = (13, 3)
    plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13, 13))
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid(grid_size, (0, 0), colspan=1, rowspan=4)
    ax2 = plt.subplot2grid(grid_size, (0, 1), colspan=1, rowspan=2)
    ax3 = plt.subplot2grid(grid_size, (2, 1), colspan=1, rowspan=2)
    ax4 = plt.subplot2grid(grid_size, (0, 2), colspan=1, rowspan=4)
    ax5 = plt.subplot2grid(grid_size, (4, 0), colspan=3, rowspan=3)
    ax6 = plt.subplot2grid(grid_size, (7, 0), colspan=3, rowspan=3)
    ax7 = plt.subplot2grid(grid_size, (10, 0), colspan=3, rowspan=3)
    fig.tight_layout(pad=3)
    fig.suptitle(f"United States and World Covid Statistics: {ytd[5:]} to {end[5:]}-2020\n", size=12, weight='bold')

    # This is all of the information needed for the graphs/charts
    world_dfs = (US, MX, BR, DE, GB, IT, FR, ES, RU, IN)
    populations = [country.Population.iloc[0] for country in world_dfs]
    cases_per50k = [country['New_cases'].sum() / populations[i] * 50000 for i, country in enumerate(world_dfs)]
    cases_per100k = [country['New_cases'].sum() / populations[i] * 100000 for i, country in enumerate(world_dfs)]
    deaths_per100k = [country['New_deaths'].sum() / populations[i] * 100000 for i, country in enumerate(world_dfs)]
    deaths_per1m = [country['New_deaths'].sum() / populations[i] * 1000000 for i, country in enumerate(world_dfs)]
    us_total_cases = US['New_cases'].sum()
    us_total_deaths = US['New_deaths'].sum()
    world_td = cdf[cdf['Date_reported'] >= ytd]
    world_total_cases = world_td['New_cases'].sum()
    world_total_deaths = world_td['New_deaths'].sum()
    us_world_cases = (us_total_cases, world_total_cases)
    us_world_deaths = (us_total_deaths, world_total_deaths)
    us_world_labels = ('$US$', '$World$')
    country_labels = ['$US$', '$Mexico$', '$Brazil$', '$Germany$', '$UK$', '$Italy$',
                      '$France$', '$Spain$', '$Russia$', '$India$']  # toggle this if you change countries
    # country_labels = [f"${country.Country.iloc[0]}$" for country in world_dfs]  # toggle this if you change countries
    label_cols = math.ceil(len(country_labels) / 2)
    explode = (0.025, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    pos = np.arange(len(country_labels))
    width = 0.25

    # \\...Pie chart for Cases per capita of 100,000 for selected countries...\\
    ax1.pie(cases_per100k, explode=explode, labels=country_labels, shadow=False, startangle=90, pctdistance=0.8,
            autopct=lambda temp: '${:.0f}$'.format(temp * sum(cases_per100k) / 100))
    ax1.set_title('Cases per capita (100,000)')

    # \\...Pie chart for Deaths per capita of 100,000 for selected countries...\\
    ax4.pie(deaths_per100k, explode=explode, labels=country_labels, shadow=False, startangle=90, pctdistance=0.8,
            autopct=lambda temp: '${:.0f}$'.format(temp * sum(deaths_per100k) / 100))
    ax4.set_title('Deaths per capita (100,000)')

    # \\...Pie Donut chart for total cases US vs World...\\
    ax2.pie(us_world_cases, labels=us_world_labels, textprops={'fontsize': 8}, colors=['#ff0000', '#7ab6ff'],
            wedgeprops=dict(width=.1), startangle=115, pctdistance=0.45,
            autopct=lambda temp: '${:.1f}$%\n$({:.0f})$'.format(temp, (temp / 100) * sum(us_world_cases)))
    ax2.set_title('USA vs World: Total Cases\n_______________________', y=-0.3)

    # \\...Pie Donut chart for total deaths US vs World...\\
    ax3.pie(us_world_deaths, labels=us_world_labels, textprops={'fontsize': 8}, colors=['#ff0000', '#7ab6ff'],
            wedgeprops=dict(width=.1), startangle=115, pctdistance=0.45,
            autopct=lambda temp: '${:.1f}$%\n$({:.0f})$'.format(temp, (temp / 100) * sum(us_world_deaths)))
    ax3.set_title('USA vs World: Total Deaths')

    # \\...Line chart for Cases for selected countries...\\
    for country in world_dfs:
        ax5.plot(country['Date_reported'], country['New_cases'] / country['Population'] * 10000000)

    ax5.set_title('Daily Covid Cases per capita (1,000,000)')
    ax5.set_ylabel('Cases')
    ax5.set_xticks(ax5.get_xticks()[::31])
    leg = ax5.legend(country_labels, loc='upper center', ncol=label_cols, fontsize=8, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.3))
    for line in leg.get_lines():
        line.set_linewidth(3.0)

    # \\...Line chart for Deaths per Capita 1,000,000 for selected countries...\\
    for country in world_dfs:
        ax6.plot(country['Date_reported'], country['New_deaths'] / country['Population'] * 10000000)

    ax6.set_title('Daily Covid Deaths per capita (1,000,000)')
    ax6.set_ylabel('Deaths')
    ax6.set_xticks(ax6.get_xticks()[::31])

    # \\...Bar chart for Deaths per Capita 50k cases/1m deaths, for selected countries...\\
    ax7.bar(pos, cases_per50k, width, alpha=0.5, color='#EE3224')
    ax7.bar([p + width for p in pos], deaths_per1m, width, alpha=0.5, color='#FFC222')
    ax7.set_ylabel('Cases/Deaths')
    ax7.set_title('Countries: Cases and Deaths per capita')
    ax7.set_xticks([p + .5 * width for p in pos])
    ax7.set_xticklabels(country_labels)
    ax7.set_xlim(min(pos) - width, max(pos) + width * 2)
    ax7.set_ylim([0, max((cases_per50k + deaths_per1m))])
    ax7.legend(['Cases per Capita (50,000)', 'Deaths per capita (1,000,000)'], loc='upper right')

    return plt


def save_plot(figure, ytd, end):
    if not os.path.exists('covid_charts'):
        os.makedirs('covid_charts')
    if ytd <= '2020-01-03':
        figure.savefig(f'covid_charts/COVID-19-chart-{end}', dpi=300)
    else:
        figure.savefig(f'covid_charts/COVID-19-chart-{ytd[5:]}-{end[5:]}', dpi=300)
    figure.show()


def main():
    stats = get_who_statistics()
    dates = get_range_date()
    figure = create_report(stats, *dates)
    save_plot(figure, *dates)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#### file: who_report_helper.py

```
# Programmer: Jeffrey Carvalho
# https://covid19.who.int/
# https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-data.csv
# https://www.kaggle.com/tanuprabhu/population-by-country-2020


import requests
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import os
import calendar


replacements = {
    'Bolivia': 'Bolivia (Plurinational State of)',
    'Brunei': 'Brunei Darussalam',
    'Caribbean Netherlands': 'Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba',
    'Channel Islands': 'Jersey',
    'Czech Republic (Czechia)': 'Czechia',
    'Côte d\'Ivoire': 'Côte d’Ivoire',
    'DR Congo': 'Democratic Republic of the Congo',
    'Faeroe Islands': 'Faroe Islands',
    'Falkland Islands': 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)',  #
    'Iran': 'Iran (Islamic Republic of)',
    'Laos': "Lao People's Democratic Republic",  #
    'Micronesia': 'Micronesia (Federated States of)',
    'Moldova': 'Republic of Moldova',
    'North Korea': "Democratic People's Republic of Korea",
    'Northern Mariana Islands': 'Northern Mariana Islands (Commonwealth of the)',
    'Russia': 'Russian Federation',
    'Saint Barthelemy': 'Saint Barthélemy',
    'Saint Kitts & Nevis': 'Saint Kitts and Nevis',
    'Saint Pierre & Miquelon': 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon',
    'Sao Tome & Principe': 'Sao Tome and Principe',
    'South Korea': 'Republic of Korea',
    'St. Vincent & Grenadines': 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines',
    'State of Palestine': 'occupied Palestinian territory, including east Jerusalem',
    'Syria': 'Syrian Arab Republic',  #
    'Tanzania': 'United Republic of Tanzania',
    'Turks and Caicos': 'Turks and Caicos Islands',
    'U.S. Virgin Islands': 'United States Virgin Islands',
    'United Kingdom': 'The United Kingdom',
    'United States': 'United States of America',
    'Venezuela': 'Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)',
    'Vietnam': 'Viet Nam',
    'Wallis & Futuna': 'Wallis and Futuna',
}


def get_who_statistics():
    # Returns the latest version WHO report or passes on a Panda Data Frame from an already downloaded CSV file
    PATH = 'https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-data.csv'
    FILE = 'WHO-COVID-19-global-data.csv'

    def dl_data():
        data_source = requests.get(PATH)
        data = data_source.content
        if not os.path.exists('data'):
            os.makedirs('data')
        covid_data = open(f'data/{FILE}', 'wb')
        covid_data.write(data)
        covid_data.close()

    who = input('Would you like to get today\'s COVID stats from WHO?\n\nType Yes to download\nPress ENTER to skip\n')
    if who.lower() == 'yes':
        dl_data()
    try:
        cdf = pd.read_csv(f'data/{FILE}')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('ERROR: File not found!\nDownloading new file now.\n')
        dl_data()
        cdf = pd.read_csv(f'data/{FILE}')
    finally:
        cdf = cdf[['Date_reported', 'Country_code', 'Country', 'New_cases', 'New_deaths', 'Cumulative_deaths']]
        world_pop = pd.read_csv('data/population_by_country_2020.csv')
        world_pop = world_pop[['Country (or dependency)', 'Population (2020)']]
        world_pop['Country (or dependency)'].replace(replacements, inplace=True)
        cdf = cdf.join(world_pop.set_index('Country (or dependency)'), on='Country')
        cdf.rename(columns={'Population (2020)': 'Population'}, inplace=True)
    return cdf


def get_range_date():
    # Returns the range of dates to use on the charts
    msg1 = '''When would you like to start the graphs at?\n\n0: for Complete data\
    \n1: for the past week\n2: for past 30 days\n3: for past 90 days\
    \n4: Select number of days to look back\n5: Select a month in 2020\n'''
    msg2 = "How many days would you like to set the chart back to?\n"
    msg3 = "What month of 2020 would you like to look at?\nEnter numeric month value (1-12)"
    today = end = dt.date.today()
    ytd = dt.date(2020, 1, 3)
    try:
        date_range = int(input(msg1))
        while date_range < 0 or date_range > 5:
            date_range = int(input(msg1))
        if date_range == 1: ytd = today - dt.timedelta(days=7)
        if date_range == 2: ytd = today - dt.timedelta(days=30)
        if date_range == 3: ytd = today - dt.timedelta(days=90)
        if date_range == 4:
            days = int(input(msg2))
            while days < 0:
                days = int(input(msg2))
            ytd = today - dt.timedelta(days=days)
        if date_range == 5:
            month = int(input(msg3))
            while month < 1 or date_range > 12:
                month = int(input(msg3))
            month_range = calendar.monthrange(2020, month)
            ytd = dt.date(2020, month, 1)
            end = dt.date(2020, month, month_range[1])
    except ValueError:
        print('PLEASE ENTER NUMBERS ONLY!\n')
        return get_range_date()
    else:
        return str(ytd), str(end)


def main():
    print('This file is used for collecting the covid data from WHO for the report')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It would help to know what the code is supposed to do -- in English, not just in code.

Answer (score 2):

```
    US = cdf[(cdf['Country_code'] == "US") &
        (cdf['Date_reported'] <= end) & 
        (cdf['Date_reported'] >= ytd)]  # US
```

You have a lot of lines like that.

- Build an array of 'US', 'MX', ...
- Have an associative array for the left part
- Use a loop to perform those 'identical' statements

(Sorry, I don't know python, so I can't write it for you.)